# Apply style to parameter in Vue-i18n

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-i18n

Having the following translation in the template:

```
<p>
{{ $t('Counter: {n}', {n: counter}) }}
</p>
```

where counter is just a number returned from the script, I would like to apply a style to "n" (to make it red, for example).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: With style attribute or class attribute on the p element. You could also have a <style scoped> in your component to style your text, with css, scss, stylus or whatever you want to use. If you want your style/class to be dynamic you could have a computed property, and use it in your template. In any case vue i18n provides translations, that's all, the text will be adjusted depending on the count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be adding HTML directly to the translation. This would make the counter always appear in red:

translation:

```
counter: 'Counter is: <span style="color: red">{n}</span>'
```

template:

```
<span v-html="$t('counter', {n: 22})" />
```

If you want it more flexible regarding color, you could add additional parameter:

```
<span v-html="$t('counter', {n: 22, color: 'green'})" />
counter: 'Counter is: <span style="color: {color}">{n}</span>'
```